# How can I configure Nginx as reverse proxy to forward subdomain

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to forward request like

`http://host.which.nginx.is.running/<foo>/<path>`

to

`http://<foo>.my.real.site/<path>`

Can I do that? And How?

Comment: Is `<foo>` a fixed list?

Comment: not really, sometime I need to add a new server but I don't want to edit the configuration

Comment: You should use the upstream option provided by nginx for this.